# Distorsion in Photoluminescence

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, interference, diffraction, photonics

I am studying photoluminescence, but I do not understand why during measurement it turns out that the signal is distorted due to appearance of a long-wavelength replica of the fundamental laser excitation.

I thought about the diffraction grating as dispersive element in the setup, but I am not sure.

Moreover how can this problem avoided? With a filter???

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Harmonics are a problem, likely emitted by the laser itself.  Many green lasers are a special up conversion from a longer IR harmonic.  A typical filter called a dichroic will have a problem because they can pass harmonics as well, you need an absorptive type filter.